# How to fix the error of get two string at the same time

Tags: c, string, loops, structure

I've got a task to input some information of some student and export it in the form of a report

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000
typedef struct
{
    char id[6];
    char name[80];
    float grade;
    char classassessment;
} exam;
void clear_buffer()
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        ;
}
char assess(float a)
{
    if (9 <= a && a <= 10)
        return 'A';
    else if (8 <= a && a < 9)
        return 'B';
    else if (6.5 <= a && a < 8)
        return 'C';
    else
        return 'D';
}
int main()
{
    char result[MAX];
    exam student[MAX];
    int n, i=0;
    printf("The number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    clear_buffer();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter student %d ID: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", student[i].id);
        clear_buffer();
        printf("Enter this student name: ");
        gets(student[i].name);
        printf("Enter this student's grade: ");
        scanf("%f", &student[i].grade);
        clear_buffer();
        result[i] = assess(student[i].grade);
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t%s\t\t\t%s\t\t%c\n", i+1, student[i].id, student[i].name, result[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling it, you can see that `student[i].id` has both ID and name while `student[i].name` still has names of the students that have just been inputted. I can not explain why it has this error.

Comment: Which error???... BTW `gets` is deprecated

Comment: Let me guess: the ids are exactly 6 characters long, so you don't have enough space for the NUL terminator in `id`, therefore the string is seen as continuing into `name`.

Comment: `gets` is not just deprecated.  It's not even in the language anymore.  And if you're using an older version of the language, it is to be avoided in all situations.  Literally the only time you should ever use `gets` is in code demonstrating why you should never use it.

Comment: Solution, make it `char id[7]` to allow six characters of `id` + NUL. And switch from `gets` (which is impossible to use safely) to `fgets` with the appropriate maximum length and you'll avoid this issue. You also probably want to prefix your `scanf` inputs with a space, e.g., `" %s"`, `" %d"`, etc., specify the maximum length for `%s`, and check the return values. Or switch from `scanf` parsing to `fgets` line-by-line into a temporary buffer and parse from there, which is a lot easier for line-based input from the user.

Comment: Oh i got your solution. I've just changed my source code as your guide and I got the right outcome. Thank you very much @Arkku

Comment: Since your problem is solved, there probably isn't much virtue in keeping the question.  I suggest deleting it — though I see it is giving you quite a lot of reputation, so that's going to be hard.  Making sure there's enough space for a null terminator is an ever-present concern in C.

Comment: @HoangNam Glad to hear it worked. Next I suggest reading up on C strings, `fgets`, `scanf`, etc until you understand the reason for these suggestions, and then you'll know more than just how to solve this particular instance of the problem. =)

Comment: Hoang Nam, if you make yourself an answer, this might survive as a Q/A pair. Otherwise it probably gets deleted.

Comment: for robust code, regarding: `scanf("%d", &n);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.   Also, there is not check to assure the value entered is <= 1000.

Comment: regarding: `gets(student[i].name);`  The function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the C language since (approx) 2009.  Suggest using `fgets()`  (which has a different parameter list)

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", student[i].id);`  1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  in the current statement, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.   2) when using the input format specifiers `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because they always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any chance of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `char result[MAX];
    exam student[MAX];`  This is very open to buffer overflows.  Suggest moving those statement to after the first call to `scanf()` and writing them like so:  `char result[n];
    exam student[n];`  Note: this makes use of the `variable length arrays` feature of C.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("%d\t%s\t\t\t%s\t\t%c\n", i+1, student[i].id, student[i].name, result[i]);`  for ease of humans reading the code and for ease of printing the code, please honor the right margin.  Note: the right margin is usually at column 72 or 80.